# Access Touch Event of Other Application in Blackberry 10 Cascades

Tags: blackberry-10, cascade, blackberry-cascades

I want to access touch events of other application from my application.

For example launch my app and then minimize it. After that launch another app and if I touch on some button then I want its x-y coordinate of that touch event in my application.

I know that there is no such api provided by blackberry but is there any other way of accessing it.

Thanks...

Comment: I'm going to say no, since that would allow you to steal passwords and do other nefarious things. Your motives may be pure, but that is generally not the kind of thing you expect to see on a BlackBerry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you've written both apps and have set up some communication between them, then no, there isn't a way to accomplish this.

Each app in BB10 operates in a sandbox. If there is a way to accomplish this, it is a flaw in the operating system, not a feature.

Comment: Can't we access blackberry OS touch logs ??? I mean blackberry OS has some log file for touch events. So, is there any way to access that log file from my application ???

Comment: Unlikely. If there is such a log, I'd expect to find it somewhere in the system files area, not in a shared area that your application would have access to.